# Is it possible to show columns really used in a view

Tags: sql-server, view

Consider a view like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test.t_test
(
    a int, 
    b int, 
    c int, 
    d int, 
    e int
)

CREATE VIEW test.v_test AS 
    WITH w_test AS  
    (
        SELECT *, c + d AS cd_computed 
        FROM test.t_test
    )
    SELECT a AS a_renamed, c, cd_computed 
    FROM w_test
```

If I do (1)

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.view_column_usage 
WHERE view_name = 'v_test'
```

I will obtain `a,b,c,d,e`

If I do (2)

```sql
SELECT c.name 
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.views v ON c.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE v.name = 'v_test'
```

I will obtain `a_renamed,c,cd_computed`

But I would like to obtain only original columns that are really use by the "planner" to do the job, so, only: `a,c,d` the other columns `b and e` are in fact useless in these view and should not be used by the "planner".

I think/hope than planner can rewrite the view before execute AS

```sql
WITH w_test AS 
(
    SELECT a, c, c + d AS cd_computed -- rewrite of this SELECT with only the usefull columns
    FROM test.t_test
)
SELECT a AS a_renamed, c, cd_computed 
FROM w_test
```

Is there any way to retrieve this information?

Comment: If you don't want columns `b` and `e` to appear in your `VIEW`'s definition there is a *very* simple solution; stop using `SELECT *`, which in this instead is parsed as `SELECT a, b, c, d, e`. You should not be using it in object definitions any way, as it has (some) gotchas, so write the columns you need explicitly and you will get the results you want. Tl;DR: The problem is your code, not SQL Server.

Comment: Also your DDL is completely invalid, both for the `TABLE` and `VIEW`. You have `a, int` (a comma between the column's name and data type), and your `VIEW`'s definition is inside paratheses, generating the error *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'."* `VIEW` definitions don't go inside paratheses.

Comment: This question comes up from time to time, but noone ever explains why they need this info? You can sometimes get the information by doing `select * from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select * from v_test', null, 1)` but it doesn't handle columns with multiple column expression sources

Comment: Thanks @ThomA for your vigilance. I have corrected the parenthesis. Note that These data are just an exemple to expose the need, and the problematic can appears even in request with no * if too much columns have been added

Comment: thanks @siggemannen for you proposition but does not actually work on data from multiple columns and all columns of table t_test appears even if they are not really necessary for the view and I don't see any information that can help me.
Know which column is used or not used may help to understand and make some adjustement or decisions

Comment: If you scroll the results, you will find the "original" table name and column, but yeah, like i wrote, it doesn't work on all kind of views, you have to parse the query or use query plans like in charlieface's answer. `Know which column is used or not used may help to understand and make some adjustement or decisions` sounds very muddy, but yeah, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system function for this.

```sql
select
  r.referenced_server_name,
  r.referenced_database_name,
  r.referenced_schema_name,
  r.referenced_entity_name,
  r.referenced_minor_name
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.v_test', 'OBJECT') r
where r.referenced_minor_name is not null;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/7E_cAP-H)

Note that `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` does not work in your case because unfortunately you are not specifying the schema name in the table references (a bad practice in itself).

---

If you only want the columns that actually end up being selected, you could parse the query plan using XQuery.

```
with xmlnamespaces (
    default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'
)
select
  x.colRef.value('@Database', 'sysname'),
  x.colRef.value('@Schema', 'sysname'),
  x.colRef.value('@Table', 'sysname'),
  x.colRef.value('@Column', 'sysname')
from @queryplan.nodes('//TableScan/DefinedValues/DefinedValue/ColumnReference') x(colRef)

union all
  
select
  x.colRef.value('@Database', 'sysname'),
  x.colRef.value('@Schema', 'sysname'),
  x.colRef.value('@Table', 'sysname'),
  x.colRef.value('@Column', 'sysname')
from @queryplan.nodes('//IndexScan/DefinedValues/DefinedValue/ColumnReference') x(colRef);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but your proposition returns all the columns (a,b,c,d,e) with the information is_select_all=1 (comes from SELECT *) and I can't distinct expected columns (a,c,d) which are the necessary/essentials columns

Comment: I guess your only other option is to create a query plan and try parse it.